# connect phpMyadmin to a LIVE MySQL database via SSH Tunnel

Tags: mysql, ssh, phpmyadmin

how to connect **phpMyadmin** to a LIVE MySQL database via SSH Tunnel

I **SSH** into the server I.e:

> ssh momo@example.ac.uk
>
> momo@eax:~ $ cd /var/www/html/

I then tried this;

> mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306 -u user -p

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

However my password is correct because i am able to **sudo** log into the mysql by doing this:

> sudo mysql

```
momo@eax:html $ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.51, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

Comment: @B001ᛦ thanks. i have taken out that part. point is i wish to connect mysqlAdmin to the live server so that i have access to the databases